# Difference between keepalive in apache2.conf and in ProxyPass

Tags: proxy, apache2, keepalive, 502-error

I am using `Apache 2.2.22`

What is the difference, if there is any, between the Keepalive directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On
```

and the directive in the `/sites-enabled` config when using ProxyPass

```
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app/ connectiontimeout=28800 timeout=28800 Keepalive=On
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### KeepAlive in main conf

Apache usually uses the HTTP 1.0 protocol to communicate, where it closes the connection after the response. The **KeepAlive On** parameter here will make apache use HTTP 1.1 where single TCP connection is used to send multiple requests/responses. This makes the server more faster when large number of requests are coming from a single client.

### KeepAlive in ProxyPass

Here the Apache will send a KeepAlive probe to the upstream server (which the request is proxied to) to keep the connection alive. This is useful when there is a firewall in between the Apache and the upstream server which drops inactive connections.

### Reference

**Main conf:** https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

**ProxyPass:** https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html